# Convert Unicode string to nested list

Tags: python, unicode

I tried to convert an unicode string like this (that I am getting from a web service):

```
value = [[u"Seba", u"10"], [u"[Gianfranco", u"80"], [u"[Marco", u"20"], [u"[Massimo", u"125"]]
```

And I want to create a nested list in order to be able to sort it via "sorted" method.

This is what I did:
First remove all the not needed ""

```
value = value.replace('"', '')
```

then strip extra [] and create list with split method:

```
valuelist = [x.split(',') for x in value.strip('[]').split('],[')]
```

Finally I am able to sort via sorted method, on second element of the nested list.

```
valuelist = sorted(valuelist,key=lambda valuelist: int((valuelist[1])), reverse=True)
```

The code is working but I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about working code.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @That1Guy And where in the Stack Overflow help center does it say that "working code" is off-topic?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) `The code is working but I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution` is open-ended, subjective, and potentially chatty.

Comment: @Biffen I'll ask question at codereview, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try

```
>>> [[i.encode('ascii', 'ignore').replace('[', '') for i in x] for x in value]
[['Seba', '10'], ['Gianfranco', '80'], ['Marco', '20'], ['Massimo', '125']]
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not correct solution because i don't get a nested list but just a list.

I need to get 
`[['Seba','10'], [['Gianfranco','80'], [['Marco','20'],[['Massimo','125']]`